# Deserialize JSon result with array

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I have some problem to read from a json. Here is the json what I get:

```
{
"LoginName": null,
"EmailAddress": null,
"FirstName": null,
"LastName": null,
"ErrorList": [
{
"ErrorNumber": 5001,
"ErrorMessage": "Validation Error: The UserName field is required.",
"Details": null
},
{
"ErrorNumber": 5001,
"ErrorMessage": "Validation Error: The Password field is required.",
"Details": null
},
{
"ErrorNumber": 1,
"ErrorMessage": "The username or password is not correct!",
"Details": null
}
]
}
```

Here are my classes:

```
[DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "LoginName")]
        public string loginName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "EmailAddress")]
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ErrorList")]
        public ErrorList[] errorList { get; set; }
    }
[DataContract]
    public class ErrorList
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "ErrorNumber")]
        public int errorNumber { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ErrorMessage")]
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

I can get for example the LoginName and EmailAddress, but I can't get the element of ErrorList.
Here is the code for deserialize the json result:

```
var res = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(res);
Email.Text = answer.emailAddress;
```

It works, but I don't reach the array.
Anyone has any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You're missing ErrorList.Details

Comment: With json.net, undefined property is just ignored.

Comment: ErrorList.Details is missing? From where?

Comment: In your ErrorList class, you do not have "Details" property.

Comment: It's true, but I don't know the type of "Details" property exactly. I guess it is a string, but if I skip it, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Abdurrahman Köken stated, maybe you should use `JSON.NET` attributes instead of `System.Runtime.Serialization`.

Still, this code has nothing wrong with it. Error is somewhere else. Using your `User` class as-is, with provided JSON, and deserializing it as `var answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(yourJsonHere);` gives the following:

[image]

So, after deserialization

```
answer.errorList.ToList().ForEach(error => 
    Console.WriteLine(@"{0}={1}", error.errorNumber, error.errorMessage));
```

Outputs

```
5001=Validation Error: The UserName field is required. 
5001=Validation Error: The Password field is required. 
1=The username or password is not correct!
```

Comment: I use the JSON.NET (by Newtonsoft). I tried your code, but at first my app is a WP8.1 app, so I can't use the console.writeline. On the other hand I can't use the foreach method after the answer.errorList.ToList()

Comment: You can still inspect `answer` in QuickWatch? `ForEach` should be available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Yes, ForEach should be available, but is not. I recently has started develop for WP8.1, and I meets a lot of issue. For example this. I will try the QuickWatch.

Comment: I've debugged my app and it's working now. The problem was that the ErrorList related property was in a try block and the catch was empty. I had an exception before the mentioned line, so the errorlist has never run. Thanks for the idea that I should debug.

Answer (score 1):

You should change DataMember attributes with JsonProperty. This should work:

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("LoginName")]
    public string loginName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EmailAddress")]
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LastName")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ErrorList")]
    public ErrorList[] errorList { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorList
{
    [JsonProperty("ErrorNumber")]
    public int errorNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ErrorMessage")]
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 for that, it's "cleaner" to use JSON.NET attributes. Add `[JsonObject]` and it's prefect :). But fact remains, original code works like charm, too...

Comment: Unfortunately it works only with User class, but doesn't with ErrorList class. So, this is the same.

Comment: See my answer, it does... with both.